# How to explain path under /sys/bus/hid/devices

Tags: linux, kernel, hid

I am studying about HID driver, and there is one thing I cannot find out any document about it.
Hope someone can help me.

When a HID device mount, I can found it on /sys/bus/hid/devices, it may looks like

> 0003:045E:0773.0002

Now, I known its format should be BUS:VID:PID.N.
My question is, what is the N (in above example, 0002)? A HID mounting order? Or a index?
And where can I find the document about this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N is just a unique number - in other words, mounting order, though relying on that would be risky.

You can see where it is assigned in the source of `hid_add_device` [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.12/source/drivers/hid/hid-core.c#L2433):

```c
dev_set_name(&hdev->dev, "%04X:%04X:%04X.%04X", hdev->bus,
             hdev->vendor, hdev->product, atomic_inc_return(&id));
```

You didn't ask about the other fields, but for completeness:

- The first field is the "bus type" - ie, the I/O system, and is one of the hardcoded values starting at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.12/source/include/uapi/linux/input.h#L251.
- The second and third fields are the vendor and product IDs read from the device.